# Why does Snape read an article about Harry from Witch Weekly?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, severus-snape

What is Snape’s motivation in the scene in the Potions lesson, during which Snape reads to the class an article about Harry from Witch Weekly?

Comment: That Snape is a nasty fellow?

Comment: So there are no hidden motives?

Comment: What hidden motives would there be, when Snape is trying to make Harry upset, which is something he does literally *all the time* and has *very obvious motives* for?

Comment: Are you asking "what are Snape's motives in this scene" or "why did J.K. Rowling put this scene in the book"? To me, your use of the word "existential" suggests the latter, i.e. "why does this scene exist?". http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/the-meaning-of-existential

Comment: I mean "what are Snape's motives in this scene"

Comment: In that case, I would suggest editing your question to make that a little clearer. The word "existential" doesn't add anything, except confusion.

Comment: @Radhil, upset Harry? For that matter, he makes Harry angry.

Comment: The question clearly isn't opinion-based, in my view. Snape's viewpoint is given in the scene in question, as Bellatrix's answer points out.

Answer (score 4):

## Snape is annoyed with them reading it in class.

Snape catches Harry, Ron, and Hermione talking in class, and then discovered them reading the issue of Witch Weekly under their desks. He then noticed that the article was about Harry, and since Snape thinks Harry very much enjoys the attention, decides to use that against him and read the article to humiliate him.

> “Ah … reading magazines under the table as well?’ Snape added, snatching up the copy of Witch Weekly. ‘A further ten points from Gryffindor … oh, but of course …’ Snape’s black eyes glittered as they fell on Rita Skeeter’s article. ‘Potter has to keep up with his press cuttings …’
>   The dungeon rang with the Slytherins’ laughter, and an unpleasant smile curled Snape’s thin mouth. To Harry’s fury, he began to read the article aloud.
>
> ‘*Harry Potter’s Secret Heartache …* dear, dear, Potter, what’s ailing you now? *A boy like no other, perhaps …*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 27 (Padfoot Returns)*</sup></sub>

He separates Harry, Ron, and Hermione from each other so they’d no longer be able to distract each other.

> “*… Harry Potter’s well-wishers must hope that, next time, he bestows his heart upon a worthier candidate.* How very touching,’ sneered Snape, rolling up the magazine to continued gales of laughter from the Slytherins. ‘Well, I think I had better separate the three of you, so you can keep your minds on your potions rather than your tangled love lives.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 27 (Padfoot Returns)*</sup></sub>

It’s clear Snape thinks all the attention is going right to Harry’s head, and Harry is letting it make him feel invisible and immune to consequences. In addition, when he gets Harry alone, he says he’s sure Harry broke into his stores of ingredients to make Polyjuice Potion, so he’d have been annoyed with Harry because of that before class even started.

> “You might be labouring under the delusion that the entire wizarding world is impressed with you,’ Snape went on, so quietly that no one else could hear him (Harry continued to pound his scarab beetles, even though he had already reduced them to a very fine powder), ‘but I don’t care how many times your picture appears in the papers. To me, Potter, you are nothing but a nasty little boy who considers rules to be beneath him.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 27 (Padfoot Returns)*</sup></sub>

Comment: Plus, Snape is unpleasant. He genuinely enjoys picking on people - not just Harry but Neville and others.

Comment: @Bellatrix, Snape, scoundrel, enjoyed the process of humiliation of poor Harry? Hmm..
But I like your last sentence.